# Why does TS allow calling `forEach` on something that could be `Record<string, never>`?

Tags: typescript

Take this code: [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3miBLMIAXPAErhIzAA8mMuKA5gDTwogBuIMAfPAD7YMdRgG0AugG4AUDnwgAdADMKAUShgAFgAplSeAF5eydEggKISBjqRIAlLalA)

```
declare const slice: Record<string, never> | string[];
slice.forEach(foo => console.log(foo))
```

Slice could be a `Record<string, never>`, which as I understand it, is basically an empty object. So why does TS allow me to call `.forEach` on it? It seems like at runtime this could result in a `forEach is not a function` error.

Comment: `Record<string, never>` is not an "empty object", it's an "object which does not exist". If you replace it with `Record<string, undefined>`, you get an expected error. I'm not sure how to render this into an answer, however, since it indeed looks a little counterintuitive.

Comment: Hmm, the compiler doesn't complain though if I do `const slice: Record<string, never> = {};`

Comment: Compiler doesn't complain because never statements are meant to never run. You can check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aldIFYWu6xc) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```js
declare let slice: Record<string, never> | string[];
```

Union type returns you most common safe type. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types)

> TypeScript will only allow an operation if it is valid for every member of the union. For example, if you have the union string | number, you can’t use methods that are only available on string.

Hence, TS allows you to use methods from `string[]` only because `string` in `Record` represents more general type. It means that `string` in `Record` allows you to use any string as a key, whereas `string[]` allows you to use only array methods. So, `forEach` method is safe to use for both `string[]` and `Record<string, never>`.

As for the value. `never` is assignable to every type in typescript, whereas every type in typescript is not assignable to `never`. See [assignability table in docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#any-unknown-object-void-undefined-null-and-never-assignability)

```js
declare let never: never;
declare let fn: () => void

never = fn // error
fn = never  // ok
```

Hence, `never` is always clashed in the union with other types. See this:

```js
type Union = never | string
```

[Here, in PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652) you will find an explanation of this behavior:

> Because `never` is a subtype of every type, it is always omitted from union types and it is ignored in function return type inference as long as there are other types being returned.

So, if you have a union of Array.prototype.method with `never` -  `{forEach:(...args:any)=>any} | never`, it always ommits `never`.

This is why you are not getting an error.

Comment: thanks but I don't really understand this. You say "forEach method is safe to use for both string[] and Record<string, never>" but if I do the following I do get an error:

`declare const slice: Record<string, never>;
slice.forEach(foo => console.log(foo))`

Comment: @dipea you are right, it is an error, because `forEach` is not a function. However, if you use ` slice.forEach`, you will not get an error. It is mean that you are allowed to use property `forEach` , but you are not allowed to call it or do anything else